# Adding a background image in python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, background, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to add a background image to a canvas in Python. So far the code looks like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

... other stuffs

root=Tk()
canvasWidth=600
canvasHeight=400
self.canvas=Canvas(root,width=canvasWidth,height=canvasHeight)
backgroundImage=root.PhotoImage("D:\Documents\Background.png")
backgroundLabel=root.Label(parent,image=backgroundImage)
backgroundLabel.place(x=0,y=0,relWidth=1,relHeight=1)
self.canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

It's returning an AttributeError: PhotoImage

Answer (score 10):

[`PhotoImage`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) is not an attribute of the `Tk()` instances (`root`). It is a class from `Tkinter`.

So, you must use:

```
backgroundImage = PhotoImage("D:\Documents\Background.gif")
```

Beware also `Label` is a class from `Tkinter`...

Edit:

Unfortunately, `Tkinter.PhotoImage` only works with gif files (and PPM).
If you need to read png files you can use the `PhotoImage` (yes, same name) class in the `ImageTk` module from `PIL`.

So that, this will put your png image in the canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Python27/programas/zimages/gato.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

So... how do I load the image into the canvas?

Comment: Is it still possible to draw other stuffs over the image?

Answer (score 0):

just change to :

```
    image = Image.open("~~~path.png")
    backgroundImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

believe me this will 100% work

Comment: What did you do? I did the same and it worked. Perhaps older version. Btw this is 5 year old thread.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Python27/programas/zimages/gato.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65252059/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `root` to Attribute `PhotoImage` this is impossible!
`root` is your window `Tk()` class so you cant Attribute it for `PhotoImage` because it's dosen't have it so you see `AttributeError` `tkinter.Tk()` and `tkinter.PhotoImage` is a different classes. and the same with `tkinter.Label`.

your code will not working with `root.PhotoImage` and `root.Label`.
try to `PhotoImage` and `Label` directly.

to create a `Label`:

```py
backgroundlabel = Label(parent, image=img)
```

if use any types of `png` or `jpg` and `jpeg` you can't draw it with just `PhotoImage` you will need [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library

```
pip3 install PIL
```

when you have it use it like:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk # import image so you can append the path and imagetk so you can convert it as PhotoImage
```

now get your full path image like:

```
C:/.../img.png
```

Now use it :

```py
path = "C:/.../img.png"         # Get the image full path
load = Image.open(path)         # load that path
img  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load) # convert the load to PhotoImage
```

now you have your code work.

full code:

```py
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

... other stuffs

root            = Tk()
canvasWidth     = 600
canvasHeight    = 400
self.canvas     = Canvas(root,width=canvasWidth,height=canvasHeight)
path            = "D:\Documents\Background.png"  # Get the image full path
load            = Image.open(path)               # load that path
img             = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
backgroundLabel = Label(parent,image=img)
backgroundLabel .place(x=0,y=0,relWidth=1,relHeight=1)
self.canvas     .pack()
root            .mainloop()
```

Hope this will helpfull.