# Can you set a tkinter background image without adding a new canvas element?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a Python tkinter program simplified to

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=200, width=200, bg="salmon")
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

def click(event):
    print(event.x)
    print(event.y)

def release(event):
    print(event.x)
    print(event.y)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)

root.mainloop()
```

with a Canvas as the main element. Canvas has click/release events bound to it (e.g. returning `event.x` and `event.y`). I want to add a background image to the canvas in this manner:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='/path/to/image.png')
```

I have managed to set a background image by creating an image on the canvas using `canvas.create_image` method, as explained in [Adding a background image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637028/adding-a-background-image-in-python). However, this broke my program as `event.x` and `event.y` return position of the background image.

I am looking for a solution that would force me to change the least of the existing code.

Comment: If you give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this code we can provide the proper feedback to your question.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I have edited my question providing very simplified code.

Comment: You are trying to add an image as a background color with this line: `canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='/path/to/image.png')`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech no, I know this is not possible. I would like my background image to act like a background colour (not interfering with my bind events).

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted. It will not interfere with your bindings. I tested it on my end and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use `PhotoImage` to load the image for use then we use `create_image` to set that image to the canvas.

Give this a shot:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=200, width=200, bg="salmon")
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

def click(event):
    print(event.x)
    print(event.y)

def release(event):
    print(event.x)
    print(event.y)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)

my_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/image.png')
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image=my_image, anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to create a background image on a canvas is to create an image object on the canvas. Doing so will not affect the coordinates returned by the bound functions in your example.